# How do I use webcron for Job.Execute?

Tags: wordpress, cron, cron-job, scheduled-job

I just got started with setting up a small implementation of civicrm. We aren't heavy-users but I want to be able to get the cron jobs working.

I decided to use webcron via easycron because it seemed to be the most easy solution, and the one I got working without much hassle. ( https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#webcron )

So I managed to get the ...&job=process_mailing & ...&job=version_check running. But when I replace 'process_mailing' with 'execute' I get:

```
HTTP code 500 Internal Server Error
```

What is the problem? What am I missing?

*edit*

i am using civicrm 5.10.3 on wordpress 5.1

Comment: Hi Sam, Welcome to civicrm stack exchange. To help people be able to answer your question it often helps to include the version of civicrm (and your cms) as well. In this case if possible would be great if you could check your logs to see if there are any errors there that correspond to the times you are triggering the post/get requests. This is a great little extension that makes it easy to check your civicrm log file - https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer/.

Comment: http code 500 errors usually show in the web server log (e.g. the apache logs), so check there too.

Comment: You can also check the response in the Chrome browser dev tool under the network section. That may give you details.